# How could I access global method from class method both are in the same module

Tags: ruby

I got this error

> NoMethodError (undefined method `get_routes' for

How could I access `get_routes` from `Sample.run`

```
module FlightUtil
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def get_routes(from="TAIPEI", to="OSAKA")
    ~~~
  end

  class Sample
    def run
     get_routes("A", "B")
    end
  end


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the module FlightUtil in the Sample class.

```
module FlightUtil
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def get_routes(from="TAIPEI", to="OSAKA")
    ~~~
  end

  class Sample
    include FlightUtil
    def run
     get_routes("A", "B")
    end
  end


end
```

A Module is a collection of methods and constants. Classes nested inside of modules are used to namespace the classes. You have to include a module in order to access the module's contents (methods or constants).

Comment: it works, but it seems kind of wierd, i have to include the moudle where i am in. haha~